Chrome authentication popup appears multiple times
I am trying to automate a website using selenium python and chrome driver . During website load the chrome authentication popup comes up and I was able to provide the username and password as below :
Http://username:password@site.com/page. But the concern here is the popup comes three times until it goes inside website so that it is failing. How would I rectify this solution? I wanted to use this in headless mode.

Please read tag descriptions before using tags. From [tag:python-3.x]: "DO NOT USE UNLESS YOUR QUESTION IS FOR PYTHON 3 ONLY. Always use alongside the standard [python] tag."
